# Setting php variable based on DIV IDs in html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find a way to get Div ID values from an included file's html and use them for comparison in a php if statement. I have a page called templates.php which uses a href value to grab a certain template, in this case fullwidth.php
Initially, this gets the value from the URL and if it's 1 it loads the full page template, else it loads the half page template. That functionality works fine:

```
<!-- Get value from href -->
<?php $value = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : 1;
      if($value == 1){ 
      include 'class/fullWidth.php';
      }else{
        include 'class/halfWidth.php';
      }
?>
```

Once `$value` dictates what template to load, I'm trying to set a value `$panelType` off of the panel Div so I know which panel type to save to my database. For example, on my fullwidth.php page I have one full width panel:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth" id="full">
    <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">

    </div>
</div>
```

so back on templates.php, I would take the `#full` as the div ID and use this to set my variable `$panelType`.

Which is where I add this and try:

```
<?php $value = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : 1;
    $panel = $html->find('div[id]'); //including this to pull in DIV IDs
      if($value == 1){ 
          include 'class/fullWidth.php';
              if($panel == 'full'){
                $panelType = 1;
              }// including this block to say if the Div ID is 'full', set $panelType = 1
      }else{
        include 'class/halfWidth.php';
      }
?>
```

But this breaks the pages and it looks like a general php or formatting error. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here, maybe there's a better way to use the div ID I want for the php variable. Eventually I will expand this so I just want to know how I can modify this to just say "If the Div ID is this, set the $panelType to this, etc."

Comment: Surely this would be *far* better handled on the front-end with responsive CSS?

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the $panel inside your fullwidth template like:

```
$panel = "full";
<div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth" id="full">
    <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">

    </div>
</div>
```

and then when you load it, the second code you wrote will work ;)

but that only works, if you can set the panel manually? if there can also be other "panel id's" then this will not work and I think you have more then one id's?

if the id will always be full, i dont see why you need to check that?

Comment: I do see your concern with multiple panels, and I do have 7 different panel types. Couldn't I wrap each div in an if statement somehow?

Comment: how do you choose which is the panel you want to use? and what exactly and how do you save it in your database?

Comment: I haven't quite gotten that far on submission, because I've only tested with one panel so far, but each template page has it's own panels so once it loads the template page (which is working) I basically want to be able to get any panels in the template and set a $panelType for them

Comment: yes but how do you choose which panels should be shown? i dont really understand what you want to achieve? what is your page about, what will be placed in this panels?

Comment: how do you set your id to "full"? and how do you know which other id's you will use?

Comment: So, I've just started tackling this specific issue but I haven't been setting them, I've just got the IDs. So the full width Div manually has id of 'full' and the half width has the manual id of 'halfLeft' and 'halfRight'. I was attempting to look at that to set the conditional in php. Basically just trying to say 'if the div id is this, set the php variable to this'

Comment: that will not work with php.. you can do something similiar with jquery AFTER the page was loaded and then do your databas actions via jquey ajax

Comment: Something I just thought of, what if I called my function that would echo the ID from the database as the div ID? Then I would have something that said "if div ID = this, set variable to the same"